# How to run java code in eclipse permanently on a jump server

Tags: java, eclipse

I have used putty terminal to execute my jar file:

```
java -jar target/data-collection-web-service-0.1.0.jar
```

How do I run that JAR file permanently, so even if I close the remote connection the code should still run.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Comment: You can run your command inside `screen` or `tmux`. You may check this question: https://superuser.com/questions/236158/tmux-vs-screen